# Installing an older version of Kazam

Tags: 12.04, versions, kazam

I do not like the new version of kazam & was wandering if there is any way to install the previous version in Ubuntu 12.04 (I know the previous version runs in 12.04 as I recently upgraded it). Anyone know if this is possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can uninstall the current version and install the old version using terminal.

To remove use the command:

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge kazam
 sudo apt-get update
```

Now install a specific kazam version.

Current version of Kazam in the repository is 1.0.6. Previous version on 12.04 is Kazam 1.0.5. You can download the package from  [Launchpad site](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kazam/1.0.5-0ubuntu1)

Also check [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) on how to avoid updating a particular package.